# URL de imagem com a função the_post_thumbnail()

Tags: wordpress

Como posso extrair somente a URL (valor do atributo `src`) de uma imagem gerada pela função `the_post_thumbnail` e atribui-la a uma imagem?

O resultado que procuro seria algo como:

```
<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você está dentro do *[Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)*, a ID do post é conhecida pelo WP, então é só usar a função [`get_post_thumbnail_id()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id) sem parâmetro.
Se estiver fora do *Loop*, é questão de usar `get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id)`.

E com essa informação à mão, usar a função [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) que indica o [Leandro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9680/201).

Exemplo:

```
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
echo "<img src='$img[0]' />";
```

[Como funciona](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php): a função `the_post_thumbnail` é um simples encapsulamento pra função `get_the_post_thumbnail`, que por sua vez termina chamando a função `wp_get_attachment_image`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
  $imagem = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size, $icon );
?>
<img src="<?php echo $imagem[0]; ?>" />
```

Aqui está a [documentação](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) caso tenha alguma dúvida.